# Deploy Spring Eureka Service Registry on Azure with docker image

Tags: spring, azure, docker, spring-cloud

I created a Docker Image and loaded it via the docker hub. Then is tried to run it as a docker container and exposed the port 8080. The container is listed and the port column shows the following: 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp.

So in my opinion the service is running but I cant access it with the ip-addres/eureka.

How is it possible to open the Eureka dashboard?

Edit:
I changed the port and now the port column of the containers shows: 0.0.0.0:8761->8761/tcp

This is the log:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.5.RELEASE)

2019-07-03 12:04:04.714  INFO 1 --- [           main] d.h.d.DiscoveryServiceApplication        : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-07-03 12:04:06.481  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointId     : Endpoint ID 'service-registry' contains invalid characters, please migrate to a valid format.
2019-07-03 12:04:07.232  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=ce95a042-2fd4-339b-a733-0cc54c83f3f1
2019-07-03 12:04:07.484  INFO 1 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$f3fe9d60] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2019-07-03 12:04:08.092  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8761 (http)
2019-07-03 12:04:08.166  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-07-03 12:04:08.170  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.19]
2019-07-03 12:04:08.352  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-07-03 12:04:08.352  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3607 ms
2019-07-03 12:04:08.606  WARN 1 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2019-07-03 12:04:08.620  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2019-07-03 12:04:08.669  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.netflix.config.DynamicPropertyFactory  : DynamicPropertyFactory is initialized with configuration sources: com.netflix.config.ConcurrentCompositeConfiguration@1863d2fe
2019-07-03 12:04:10.133  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.s.j.s.i.a.WebApplicationImpl           : Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19.1 03/11/2016 02:08 PM'
2019-07-03 12:04:10.331  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2019-07-03 12:04:10.338  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2019-07-03 12:04:10.685  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
2019-07-03 12:04:10.694  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
2019-07-03 12:04:11.443  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.a.ArchaiusAutoConfiguration      : No spring.application.name found, defaulting to 'application'
2019-07-03 12:04:11.445  WARN 1 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2019-07-03 12:04:11.445  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2019-07-03 12:04:11.843  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-07-03 12:04:12.932  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.eureka.InstanceInfoFactory       : Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
2019-07-03 12:04:13.018  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Initializing Eureka in region us-east-1
2019-07-03 12:04:13.018  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Client configured to neither register nor query for data.
2019-07-03 12:04:13.041  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1562155453040 with initial instances count: 0
2019-07-03 12:04:13.162  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.eureka.DefaultEurekaServerContext    : Initializing ...
2019-07-03 12:04:13.169  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNodes       : Adding new peer nodes [http://localhost:8761/eureka/]
2019-07-03 12:04:13.569  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2019-07-03 12:04:13.570  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
2019-07-03 12:04:13.571  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
2019-07-03 12:04:13.571  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
2019-07-03 12:04:13.841  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.eureka.cluster.PeerEurekaNodes       : Replica node URL:  http://localhost:8761/eureka/
2019-07-03 12:04:13.859  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Finished initializing remote region registries. All known remote regions: []
2019-07-03 12:04:13.860  INFO 1 --- [           main] c.n.eureka.DefaultEurekaServerContext    : Initialized
2019-07-03 12:04:13.890  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2019-07-03 12:04:14.103  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry        : Registering application unknown with eureka with status UP
2019-07-03 12:04:14.123  INFO 1 --- [      Thread-11] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap   : Setting the eureka configuration..
2019-07-03 12:04:14.138  INFO 1 --- [      Thread-11] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap   : Eureka data center value eureka.datacenter is not set, defaulting to default
2019-07-03 12:04:14.139  INFO 1 --- [      Thread-11] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap   : Eureka environment value eureka.environment is not set, defaulting to test
2019-07-03 12:04:14.181  INFO 1 --- [      Thread-11] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap   : isAws returned false
2019-07-03 12:04:14.182  INFO 1 --- [      Thread-11] o.s.c.n.e.server.EurekaServerBootstrap   : Initialized server context
2019-07-03 12:04:14.182  INFO 1 --- [      Thread-11] c.n.e.r.PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl    : Got 1 instances from neighboring DS node
2019-07-03 12:04:14.182  INFO 1 --- [      Thread-11] c.n.e.r.PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl    : Renew threshold is: 1
2019-07-03 12:04:14.183  INFO 1 --- [      Thread-11] c.n.e.r.PeerAwareInstanceRegistryImpl    : Changing status to UP
2019-07-03 12:04:14.225  INFO 1 --- [      Thread-11] e.s.EurekaServerInitializerConfiguration : Started Eureka Server
2019-07-03 12:04:14.253  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8761 (http) with context path ''
2019-07-03 12:04:14.259  INFO 1 --- [           main] d.h.d.DiscoveryServiceApplication        : Started DiscoveryServiceApplication in 12.423 seconds (JVM running for 13.3)
2019-07-03 12:05:14.187  INFO 1 --- [a-EvictionTimer] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Running the evict task with compensationTime 0ms
2019-07-03 12:06:14.187  INFO 1 --- [a-EvictionTimer] c.n.e.registry.AbstractInstanceRegistry  : Running the evict task with compensationTime 0ms
```

Container information

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS                    NAMES
8994d80a4ee2        marcelv93/service-discovery:latest   "java -Djava.securit…"   6 minutes ago       Up 6 minutes              0.0.0.0:8761->8761/tcp   api
```

Answer (score 1):

For your issue, you cannot access the container. As I know the possible reasons below:

1. the container is not running well.
2. the container is running well, but the application is not running well inside the container.
3. both container and the application is running well, but you expose a wrong port. The port is not the one that the application listens to inside the container.

So you need to check it for the point above. And I find the default port is 8761 and you need to set the configuration. Take a look at the [Containerize-Spring-Cloud-Eureka-Server](https://medium.com/@sasisugumar/containerize-spring-cloud-eureka-server-c3af66578026).

Comment: I edited my question: I think the container is running well. I also changed the ports to 8761. But wehen I type in the server ip-adress:8761/eureka I still cant access the eureka dashboard. So nothing happens...

Comment: @softwareUser Are you sure the way you use to run the image right? Does it need something like server URL? Where do you find the image?